# jqGrid: How to set the formoptions:elmsuffix dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I set the required option to my password field dynamically:

```
$("#name").jqGrid('setColProp', 'password', {
    editrules: {
        required: true
    }
});
```

And it work 's fine. But I can't set the elmsuffix:

```
$("#name").jqGrid('setColProp', 'password', {
    formoptions: {
        elmsuffix: ' *'
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oleg, thank's a lot, now I started to accept the previous answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your problem is just *where* or *when* you set the `formoptions`. Probably you tried to set the settings inside of `beforeShowForm`, but the `{formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *' }` setting should be used during constructing of the form.

So you should just use [beforeInitData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) to make the changes.