# jqgrid - dynamically load different colModel edittypes(Text box and check box) in two rows of same column

Tags: jqgrid

I'm doing some R&D work on displaying different colModel edittypes(Text box and check box) in two rows of the same column in a JqGrid. Because I need to display different edit-types for a same column depending on the back-end database values. Its possible to display different edit-types for different columns. Please help me on this to carry out my R&D work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't explained which editing mode you use. The solution of the problem can be different depend on the editing mode.

I would you recommend to change the properties of the column, for example the `edittype` value, directly before the editing of the row be started.

In case of form editing you can change the properties inside of call . In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3405961/315935) are shown how to show of hide some column property inside of `beforeShowForm` callback. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7615331/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9081762/315935) are examples of the usage `beforeInitData` which seems be the best for your case. Inside of `beforeInitData` you can change **any properties** of `colModel` before the form will be constructed.

Typical usage of inline editing consist from the calling of [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) inside of `onSelectRow` or inside of `ondblClickRow`. So one can use [setColProp](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) method for example to change column properties *before* there will be used. See examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7732536/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4308172/315935).